# How to use pinout with esp8266 from C file?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a very basic example of the task I'm trying to solve. From the main loop in `arduino.ino` I call the `sample_run()` function in `device.c` using the definition in `sample.h`. From here I'm trying to understand how I can use the GPIO pins from `device.c`. Can this be done using the arduino ide? I've attached some sample code of what I'm trying to do.

**arduino.ino**

```
#include "sample.h"
#include "esp8266/sample_init.h"

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
  sample_run();
}
```

**sample.h**

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_H
#define SAMPLE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void sample_run(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* SAMPLE_H */
```

**device.c**

```
#include "sample.h"
void sample_run(void)
{
    //I would like to turn on/off led here
}
```

Comment: Your question is not precise enough (C/C++, ESP8266 GPIO, IDE, empty sample). Did you test blink with IDE as a first step ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In device.c: `#include "Arduino.h"`

Why are you using .c files and not .cpp?

Comment: Thanks! I'm using a third party library so I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: Baloney.  You always have a choice.